# many else if conditional operator not working

Tags: javascript

i want it trigger when number is 0. when number is 1 or 2, when number is 3 or 4, when number is 5 or 6. when trigger it will change height some element. for now it always return 70px.

```
    if(y == 0){
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
    }else if(y >= 1){
        $('slpage').style.height = '70px';
    }else if(y <=4){
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
    }else if(y >= 5){
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
    }
```

thanks

Comment: why not switch() function ?

Comment: what is the y ?It's integer?

Comment: If `y` is greater than or equal to 1, you set the height to 70px. Those other conditions won't even be tested because they're in `else if` clauses; that's what `else` means: "if that wasn't true, try this".  Once a test is successful the sequence is finished.

Comment: @RajaRamachandran yes, its a integer

Comment: @AyazShah switch if the integer dependent. its means it should 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. but my situation is if 0. it trigger. if 1-2. it trigger. if 3-4. it trigger. if 5-6. it trigger.

Comment: please dont copy the answer into the question. that makes little sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider reordering your statements. So that it checks the highest first and then for lowest.

```
if(y == 0){
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
    }else if(y >= 5){
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
    }else if(y >=4){
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
    }else if(y >= 1){
        $('slpage').style.height = '120px';
    }
```

Otherwise, you end up triggering the lowest always before reaching the highest.

And I guess you made a type for the check in your third condition. Corrected.

> switch if the integer dependent. its means it should 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. but my situation is if 0. it trigger. if 1-2. it trigger. if 3-4. it trigger. if 5-6. it trigger.

Don't restrict yourself using switch just because you have to cover 2 cases at a time. `Switch` have that facility too.

```
switch (y) {
    case 0:
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        $('slpage').style.height = '120px';
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
         $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
         $('slpage').style.height = '240px';
         break;
}
```

Assuming you using Jquery, your selector of Jquery is wrong. You are missing `#` or `.` Ignore if you are not.

Comment: I thought it was jQuery too, but it is not necessarily so. It could be a $ helper function. I still find my answer the nicest looking

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah. That's true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) also

```
switch (y) {
    case 0:
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        $('slpage').style.height = '70px';
        break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
        break;
}
```

```js
function sw(y) {
    switch (y) {
        case 0:
            console.log('0px');
            break;

        case 1:
        case 2:
            console.log('70px');
            break;

        case 3:
        case 4:
            console.log('140px');
            break;
        case 5:
        case 6:
            console.log('210px');
            break;

        default:
        console.log('no value mathed value');
    }
}

sw(0);

sw(1);

sw(2);

sw(3);

sw(4);

sw(5);

sw(6);

sw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement maybe ?

```
switch (y) {
    case 0:
         $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
        break;
    case 1:        
    case 2:
        $('slpage').style.height = '70px';
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
        break;
    case 5:
    default:
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
}
```

For more infos you can check: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Please apply the switch to the code at hand - there are one case for 1,2,3

Comment: no your example is i put each integer with trigger. i only need if 0. it trigger. if 1-2. it trigger. if 3-4. it trigger. if 5-6. it trigger

Answer (score 0):

When you have y = {1,2,3,4,5,6} it satisfies the condition that it is >=1 hence it breaks it at that point. Instead change your logic from highest to lowest

```
   if(y >=5){
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
    }else if(y >= 3){
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
    }else if(y >=1){
        $('slpage').style.height = '70';
    }else {
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

```
var h = 0;
     if (y >= 5) h = 210;
else if (y >= 3) h = 140;
else if (y >= 1) h = 70;
$('slpage').style.height = h+'px';
```

assuming

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

If you are using jQuery, you need

```
$('.slpage').css({"height": h+'px'});
```

or

```
$('#slpage').css({"height": h+'px'});
```

depending on selector

Comment: dry would be : `var h = (y + 1) * 35`

Comment: Then 2 would be 105, so no. But I was leaning in the same direction but did not have the caffeine to take it to the end.

Comment: but getting closer `Math.floor((y - 1) / 2) * 70`

Comment: @JonasW. that is not handling 0 (-70) and >5

Answer (score 0):

Better to use  `switch`:

```
switch (y) {
    case 0:
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        $('slpage').style.height = '70px';
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        $('slpage').style.height = '140px';
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
        $('slpage').style.height = '210px';
        break;
    default:
        $('slpage').style.height = '0px';
 }
```